# latex(VAR) command converts other concatenated strings into mathemode when latex displays it

Tags: math-mode, strings, sagetex

Using sagetex in latex; it appears that using the latex() command converts any concatenated strings to that term into math-mode, rather than strings. See the MWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
StartStr = 'Beginning string'
EndStr = 'trailing string.'
WorkingStr = StartStr + " and "+ EndStr
BrokeStr = StartStr + latex(11/2) + EndStr
\end{sagesilent}

Notice that "$\sage{StartStr}$", "$\sage{EndStr}$", and "$\sage{WorkingStr}$" are all printed as text.

But "$\sage{BrokeStr}$" converts the entire string into math-mode and breaks everything.
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to stop sage from converting the entire string to latex math-mode and still be able to save the entire sentence in one variable as well as maintaining the correct mathematical display of the latex content (eg showing it as an actual fraction instead of the string '11/2').

To be clear my specific requirements are:

1. Have a string concatenated with properly rendered math (not necessarily via the latex() command, but I don't see any other options that make sense?) and have all of the individual pieces rendered correctly; the string as strings and the math as actual math
2. Have the above saved into *a single sage variable*; as oppose to having a sequence of variables called in some order to achieve the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, posted on CTAN [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex), you'll find starting on page 6 that there are macros `\sage`, `\sagestr`, `\percent`, and `\sageplot`. The `\sage` macro is for numerical data and `\sagestr` is for string data. I've adjusted your code so that it uses `\sagestr`. To work numerical data in (a = 11/2) I've added it to your strings using using a raw string so that the slash doesn't cause a problem. This is done by using `numerator()` and `denominator()` on your number to determine what integers to go into making the LaTeX fraction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
a = 11/2
StartStr = 'Beginning string'
EndStr = 'trailing string.'
WorkingStr = StartStr + " and "+ EndStr
BrokeStr = (StartStr + r" $\frac{%s}{%s}$ " + EndStr)%(a.numerator(),a.denominator())
\end{sagesilent}
Notice that \sagestr{StartStr}, \sagestr{EndStr}, and \sagestr{WorkingStr} are all printed as text.

Now \sagestr{BrokeStr} prints the entire string.
\end{document}
```

The output in Cocalc is:

[image]

EDIT: Since your comment specifies you would like the fraction inserted into the string, I've edited my code to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and sorry for the late comment)! However, my goal is to get 11/2 to appear as if it were being typeset in latex using $\frac{11}{2}$; as oppose to appearing as "11/2" or as "5.5".

Comment: That can be easily accomplished by inserting the LaTeX command. If you know the fraction ahead of time you can insert the numerator and denominator. If you don't know the fraction ahead of time then `numerator()` and `denominator()` can get them. I've edited my post to show you how.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and this works great with sagestr. I'll mark this as correct in 24 hours (remind me if I don't) but it turns out that the document class I'm using doesn't allow me to use sagestr reliably for reasons that aren't really in my control. Is it possible to accomplish this with just the \sage command, despite the ugly string execution from \sage printing strings? If not that would also be good to know; and thanks again for the nice solutions, including the %'s with a.numerator() and b.numerator() which I was not aware of.

Comment: I am unable to make things work just using `\sage{}`. I think your best chance is to fiddle with how your document class works in order to make `\sagestr` reliable.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the information, just knowing that I probably shouldn't waste my time trying to make `\sage` work is tremendously useful. Time to dig through the doc class and see if I can fix it from that angle, which is probably the better long-term solution anyway. Thanks again! Marked as accepted answer.